# Joining multiple columns in table1 with multiple columns in table2 with additional condition MySql

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have `table_1` with unique records of IDs and multiple columns of data

and

`table_2` with multiple rows concerning particular ID and multiple columns. One of the column in `table2` is, say, time_lapse.

I need those two tables joined with all columns saved but with only those rows from `table2` with highest time_lapse value.

I was trying this way...

```
create table as new_table 
select table1.*, table2.* from 
table1 left join table2
on table1.id=table2.id
where time_lapse=
(select max(time_lapse) from table2
group by id);
```

... but it failed.

Any suggestions for a newbie? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should know that "but it failed" is not a very descriptive way to describe your problem. Did it give an error message? If so, what was the error? Did it have no error, but didn't give the result you were expecting? If so, what were you expecting and what did it do instead? Also, what is the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for each table? Please help us help you.

Comment: What is the primary key of `table2`? Post the schema as Bill suggested.

Comment: As the actual table was quite weighty I decided to post a question based on simplified  "dummy" substitute. As far as original tables are concerned, there is only one primary key (id) in table1, and no primary key in table2 whatsoever. I am novice in a field so sorry for my clumsiness. The answer by @Thorsten Kettner turned out to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. But you are selecting the maximum `time_lapse` per `id` and then you act as if you had only selected one record with only one `time_lapse`. Use `IN` and have the `id` in the select list of your subquery:

```
create table as new_table 
select table1.*, table2.* from 
table1 left join table2
on table1.id=table2.id
where (table2.id, table2.time_lapse) in
(select id, max(time_lapse) from table2
group by id);
```

Then you are outer-joining table2, but want certain criteria on it in the `WHERE` clause. That doesn't work (as columns in outer-joined records are null).

The same query a tad prettier with a real outer join:

```
create table as new_table 
select t1.*, t2.* 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
                    and (t2.id, t2.time_lapse) in
                        (select id, max(time_lapse) from table2 group by id);
```